# Open source, self hosted videoconference server

Tags: gratis, open-source, ubuntu, video-editing, self-hosted

I'm looking for a videoconference software with the following requirements:

- free
- open source
- I can host it easily on a personal Ubuntu server (doesn't matter the version)
- has a [GDPR](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679&from=EN)-compliant privacy policy
- allows calls with 5 (or more) users
- has a Windows or browser-based client (it must be free, open source and [GDPR](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679&from=EN)-compliant too)

What could I use?

Comment: Nextcloud Talk? Comes as a Nextcloud app. Even has a native app for Android. Can be used in a web browser, and self-hosted.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you are looking for:

[Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) is a set of open-source projects that allows you to build and deploy secure videoconferencing solutions.

The source code is [here](https://github.com/jitsi).

You can use the browser as the client (multiplatform), and there is an SDK for Android and iOS.

The are no fixed limits (your resources will define that). No privacy information. The traffic is not end-to-end encrypted, just between the server and the clients. If you set your own instance, it would be up to you to comply with GDPR. If instead of auditing the source you would like to ask them about possible privacy issues, [this](https://community.jitsi.org/) would be the place to do it.

It is already packaged for Debian and Ubuntu. You also have instructions on [how to set up up your own instance](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/quick-install.md).

Comment: It looks interesting but I can't find their privacy policy.

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted to run your own instance.

Comment: I want to run my own instance but I also want to know how it will use my data - e.g. if it will send system information to the producer. I know open source software ususally respects users' privacy but I'm not sure how much I can trust a producer that doesn't have a privacy policy for its own website.

Comment: If you have the full source, that's all you need to trust/audit. They have a community though, you might search in the forum and write to them if you don't find the answer: https://community.jitsi.org/

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I updated the answer. Hope that does it.